# Prove that (a,b) a,b $\in Q$ is a topological base on $ \mathbb{R} $ with the usual topology.

Tags: general-topology

Prove that (a,b) a,b $\in Q$ is a topological base on $ \mathbb{R} $ with the usual topology.

Proof:  I have to prove that for every $V \in T_{ \mathbb{R} }$ where $T_{  \mathbb{R} }$ is the usual topology in $ \mathbb{R} $, is a union of $(a,b)\subset \mathbb{R} $ where $a$,$b$ $\in Q$ .

So $V=\bigcup_{i\in I}  (x,y)$ since it is open in $ \mathbb{R} $.
Now I have to prove $V=\bigcup_{k\in V}(a,b)$ $a$,$b$ $\in Q$.

I want to use the fact that $\overline Q=R$ which means for every $x \in R$  every open neighborhood $U_x \cap Q \neq \emptyset $ which means there is a $q \in Q$

$x-ε<q<x+ε$

Now I can't use that fact to prove that for any element in a $(x,y)$ there exist a (a,b) such that $(a,b)\subset (x,y)$  and then easily prove that any open $V$ is actually the union of $(a,b)$.

******* I want to prove that it is a topological base only this way but I don't want to use analysis meaning taking sequences to prove that they go in x,y  and write (x,y)=infinite union of sequence points of rationals.*****

Comment: It is enough to prove that $(x,y)=\cup\{(a,b)\mid (a,b)\subseteq(x,y)\wedge a,b\in\mathbb Q\}$. Can you do that?

Comment: When you say that you don't want to use that every real number is the limit of a sequence of rationals, perhaps you can tell us what you think a real number actually *is*; the "sequence" property is essentially the link between rationals and reals. Without that link, you're just trying to prove some thing about topologies on subfields (worse, it's something that's not true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence you have the proof already:

Suppose $V$ is open. Let $x \in V$. This means there are $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a < x < b$ and $(a,b) \subseteq V$. Then $(a,x)$ is a non-empty open interval and thus intersects $\mathbb{Q}$ (as $\mathbb{Q}$) is dense). So there is some $q_1 \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a < q_1 < x$. Similarly we have $q_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x < q_2 < b$. So $I_x:=(q_1, q_2)$ is a rational interval that contains $x$ and such that $(q_1, q_2) \subseteq (a,b) \subseteq V$. 
Then note that $V = \bigcup\{ I_x: x \in V\}$ (all intervals are subsets of $V$ and also $x \in V$ is at least in $I_x$). So $V$ is a union of rational intervals.

The essence is that the denseness of $\mathbb{Q}$ (and the fact that the order on $\mathbb{R}$ has no gaps, so that $a < x$ implies $(a,x) \neq \emptyset$) implies that inside every open interval containing $x$ we have a rational interval containing $x$.

Comment: Damn i did not know why my head couldnt connect them  when i had all the pieces..... i hate it.Thank you!!

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis you’re welcome.